# How to add data in the footerFormat of tooltip of highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to add a date in the footerFormat of tooltip, the date doesn't define in the series or in the xAxis/yAxis, but I should add that matched.

My code:

tooltip: {footerFormat: Date: '+data_list[8]+'',
        shared: true,
        crosshairs: true},

data_list[8] include list of date

My result:

[image]

As you see, I get all the columns date

Comment: use tooltip `formatter: function(){}`

Comment: or refer to this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/Kc23N/3/

Comment: you brougth me an example that use with a data from series, x and y. but me date list doesn't exist in the sere, x, or y. 
this is my series data and x data:
    },
];
xAxis: {
    categories: data_list[6],
}

Comment: this is my series data and x data:
series:[{ name: 'Under Debug', data: data[4], type: 'column', color: '#cccccc', yAxis: 0},
{name: 'No Run', data: data[3],: 'column', color: '#5f5e60', yAxis: 0}, ....];
xAxis: { categories: data_list[6],}

Comment: You cannot do this with footerFormat. You need to define the whole tooltip in the formatter and track your date manually for each point. If you update your question with the code or recreate your problem on jsfiddle/codepen/etc. my help will be more specific.

Comment: I write my code on https://jsfiddle.net/sarih/8v6a3h2j/ thx!